# Actualizar un campo en Mongoose si el nuevo valor no es nulo?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

teniendo un Schema como este:

```
const FarmSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  extension: {
    extension: {
      type: Number,
      min: 1,
      max: 1000,
      required: true
    },
    measure: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['Hectareas', 'Manzanas'],
      required: true
    }
  },
  animals: [mongoose.model('Animal').schema],
  outs: {
    type: Array,
    required: true
  },
  outs: {
    type: Array,
    required: true
  },
  plans: {
    type: Array,
    required: true
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true,
  useNestedStrict: true
});
```

Y en el controller para actualizar Farms esto:

```
exports.update = (req, res) => {
  User.update(
    {
      username: req.params.username,
      'farms._id' : req.params.idFarm
    },
    {
      $set: { // fix me 
        'farms.$.name': req.body.name,
        'farms.$.extension': req.body.extension
      }
    }
  )
    .then(farm => {
      res.send(farm);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
          err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving all farms."
      });
    });
};
```

Lo que quiero es que si el usuario solo desea modificar el campo 'name', se mande un JSON como este al servidor y solo actualize el campo name sin alterar el campo 'extension':

```
{
    "name": "Finca 99"
}
```

El problema es que si hago esto, el campo 'extension' se vuelve null o viceversa.

Answer (score 1):

Ya probaste esto:

```
var myquery = { name: "Tu nombre actual" };
var newvalues = { $set: {name: "Finca 99"} };
dbo.collection("customers").updateOne(myquery, newvalues, function(err, res) {...
```

Cuentame si probaste hacer el update de esta manera o la estás haciendo de alguna otra, puedes ver la documentación completa en https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_update.asp

Cualquier duda, me avisas.

Saludos!